# How can I find all the air leaks and insulation gaps in my finished attic?

Tags: insulation, air-conditioning, attic-conversion, air-leaks, air-sealing

I have a finished attic which gets hot very quickly, requiring running the central AC excessively and due to the imbalance, the downstairs tends to get too cold while the finished attic is still too warm. (Don't worry, I am addressing the HVAC imbalance separately from this post.)

I've gone through and sealed around outlets and other visible cracks and gaps but I believe I still have significant leaks somewhere. Is there a trick I can use to discover where the air or heat is passing through?

Comment: A smoke grenade may show lots of holes... but perhaps those smoke sticks or matches might be better.

Comment: I am not understanding the correlation between it being too hot and having leaks.

Comment: Hot air rises, so might come from floor.  Do you have windows where sun shines though, that can also raise temperature fast?  Do you have vents to let hot escape?

Comment: @AlaskaMan In places other than Alaska, it is hot outside and cool inside in the summer. :D

Comment: Can be a case where you did the job too well.  Seal everything up tight and heat cannot go anywhere.  Might just need to have a vent(fan powered) near top to let heat out.

Comment: Why do you want the attic to be cool?  What is the objective?  As the other comments explain, heat enters (in summer) through the roof and airflow usually cools it off.  But installing a fan to cool a well insulated unfinished space seems unnecessary, unless we know the objective.

Comment: @jay613  OP says it is finished, not unfinished.

Comment: If heat is the sole concern, you shouldn't seal the leaks in the attic, unless you have AC in it, the leaks allow the hot air to escape, similar to the effect of sitting in a car under a sunny hot day - roll the window down. Otherwise, due to volume expansion, the hot air will be forced down into the living space below. You shall focus on sealing the ceiling and access opening to the attic. Also, as suggested, attic fan helps.

Comment: @crip659 oops.  Thanks.   @-brentonstrine can you describe your AC configuration?  Window units?  Mini splits? Central?  Does the attic have its own central zone or is it shared with the floor below?  Are there vents in the attic?  Is there a return in the attic? 
 Where is/are the thermostat(s)?    If the finished space is well sealed from the unfinished parts of the attic you should look to air circulation and cooling for the answer.  Is the finished attic open to the floor below?  Is there a door and is it normally open or closed?

Comment: Are you familiar with the terms "solar load" or "solar gain"?

Comment: What is outside roof colour?   Black is very hot, white can be almost cool.  Insulation slows down heat lost/gain, does not stop it(unless talking about 3 or 4 feet, very slow)

Comment: Lots of people seem to be missing that this is a finished attic. Or at least some of it. There are unfinished portions behind the kneewalls. The finished portion is connected to central air via traditional ducts.

Comment: @jay613 "If the finished space is well sealed from the unfinished parts of the attic" <- this is exactly the problem. I don't think it is well sealed, but I'm trying to find a way to find all the areas that need to be fixed.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes I am aware that the sun heats the roof which heats the attic. Hence the importance of air sealing and insulation between the finished and unfinished portion of the attic.

Comment: @brentonstrine I understand what you mean but I'm giving your efforts the benefit of the doubt, you obviously tried to close any big gaps so what I'm saying is, you might be well into diminishing or long-vanished returns.    In my finished attic I know there are some poorly sealed and poorly insulated areas and after closing up the gaping holes, I solved the heat problem by making a few changes to the central air and that hit the bullseye.  If you have central air in the attic served as one zone with the floor below it I can make some suggestions.

Comment: @jay613 Ok. It's central air from the crawl space that has a duct that goes through a shaft to the attic, through the unconditioned space, into two finished attic rooms. No zoning. The attic is vented but does not have soffits. I'm halfway through the process of installing a return from the attic. Doors can be open or closed.

Comment: @jay613 Taking a step back: there are many problems, but a major problem is low air flow coming out of the two registers to the finished attic rooms. It's not cold enough and not fast enough. Beyond that, the attic gets hot by 10am while downstairs can stay cool all day thus not trigger the thermostat to turn on. 

I am trying to solve this with every prong. I'm having trouble figuring out how to add extra insulation, (without trapping moisture in the wall) how to insulate the ductwork, how to boost the airflow... look at my recent question history you will see the many problems I'm facing.

Comment: @brentonstrine I asked and answered this question about how I improved A/C service to my attic, and I recommend you look at that before you put more energy into finding small cracks.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221875/how-can-i-make-a-finished-attic-cooler-and-all-bedrooms-comfortable-central-a-c

Answer (score 1):

Two separate issues here:

#### Attics Get Hot!

This is a fact of life. Attics heat up from the sun all day long. Color and type of roof can make some difference (reflection vs. absorption), but it is quite normal for an attic to get really hot. The usual solution is an attic fan. This can be thermostatically controlled so it only runs when hot. For an attic fan to work, you need to have the fan on one end and air coming in from elsewhere (but not from your house below).

If your attic is really getting hot from your house, or if your attic gets hot and the hot air goes down into your house, then you get to checking for leaks:

#### Thermal Imaging

There are [thermal (infrared) cameras](https://amzn.to/3mA8QEL) available as standalone devices, and also as add-ons for handheld computers (aka smart phones):

[image: FLIR camera]

You can either buy something (if you like gadgets and can justify it to yourself) or borrow or rent one.